# Replacement to toBeVisible() in Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I installed detox for E2E testing with react-native, and i saw that after init command there is a
firstTest.e2e.js file, now when i changed the file to be .ts i get:

> Property 'toBeVisible' does not exist on type
> 'JestMatchersShape<Matchers<void, DetoxAny>, Matchers<Promise,
> DetoxAny>>

```
 it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('check'))).toBeVisible();
    await element(by.id('check')).tap();
  });
```

I think that jest deprecated toBeVisible(), i saw the document and i didn't find a replacement.
Someone know how can i replace it ?

Comment: toBeVisible is unrelated to Jest itself. It's https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom .

Comment: @Estus Flask  Thanks !